# Concat multiple (self-generated) videos using ffmpeg on raspbian linux

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, raspbian

I am a very talented sleep talker, so I decided to write a solution that records the things I talk at night to make funny videos with subtitles of it. The project is nearly done, but I got a big problem with concating videos I generated before.

The video parts are generated from single png frames using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 15 -i "${images_file_path}" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${video_file_path}"
```

Then the sound is added using this command (got this from [#9049970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049970/how-to-combine-a-mp4-video-with-a-wav-audio-with-an-offset-in-ffmpeg-from-comm) and [#11779490](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/ffmpeg-how-to-add-new-audio-not-mixing-in-video)):

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${video_file_path}" -i "${mp3_file_path}" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -acodec copy -shortest "${final_video_file_path}"
```

All this is causing no problems so far, but I think it may be relevant to know how the videos are generated. I can watch all this and get valid video and sound - the full source code of this first part can be found [here](https://github.com/blaues0cke/PiSleepTalk/blob/master/bash/generate-video.sh).

Now I added a feature that is able to generate "full videos" containing a title and a various number of previously generated "video parts" using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i "${video_list_path}" -filter_complex "${filter_string} concat=n=${input_file_counter}:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "${full_video_path}"
```

But something is wrong with it and I get this error:

```
Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0:v:0] [1:v:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [4:v:0] [4:a:0] [5:v:0] [6:v:0] [6:a:0] [7:v:0] concat=n=8:v=1:a=1 [v] [a].
```

The full output is:

```
ffmpeg version N-77213-g7c1c453 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-gpl --prefix=/usr --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --disable-mmx
  libavutil      55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavcodec     57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 20.100 /  6. 20.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xc2e900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from '/usr/sleeptalk/records-rendered/3enguzpuu2gw0ogk8wkko/videos.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 61 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 58 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0:v:0] [1:v:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [4:v:0] [4:a:0] [5:v:0] [6:v:0] [6:a:0] [7:v:0] concat=n=8:v=1:a=1 [v] [a].
```

I also wrote a test case so you can reproduce this on your local machine. Download the files [from my dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5413276/ffmpeg-test.zip). Also, the full script that renders the "final move" can be found [here](https://github.com/blaues0cke/PiSleepTalk/blob/master/bash/render-video.sh).

Would be great to get an Idea, got struggle to fix this the last two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using both the concat demuxer as well as the concat filter. Skip the latter, because

**a**) it's unnecessary and

**b**) I don't believe the demuxer is inducting all input files as separate inputs so the indices beyond `0` don't make sense. Also, the concat filter needs equal number of streams per input file, and their input assignment has to be pair-wise i.e. `[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0]...`.

Instead, use

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i "${video_list_textfile}" -c copy "${full_video_path}"
```

where `${video_list_textfile}` is a text file of the form

```
file 'file1.mp4'
file 'file2.mp4'
file 'file3.mp4'
...
```

Comment: Damn, this works pretty well, but I have no audio at all after using this command. ffmpeg is reporting a lot of errors, like `[mp4 @ 0x7f8eeb00a400] aac bitstream error` or `Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers`.

Comment: Do all input files have audio? And with the same properties? For global headers, insert `-flags +global_header`.

Comment: I am on it to check this, recognized that 1-3.mp4 have mp3 as audio and the rest of the files uses aac. I hope this will fix my problems.

Comment: Yeah, same audio (and video) properties needed across files.