# Merging video to an audio file from in between or at a particular time

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg

I am aiming to merge couple of media files.
So there is one audio file generated for say x minutes.And in between this duration multiple video files are generated at different timestamps (but all ends at or before that audio file ).
So I want to merge them such that different video files are merged with audio only at their respective times.
For eg -Following would be appearance of merged file, where A = audio stream and Vx = video streams

```
   Start
    2:00 A
    2:07 A + V1
    2:13 A + V2
    2:17 A + V3
    2:24 A
   Finish
```

Should I use ffmpeg concatenation ? but ot sure it supports merging that starts at a particular time interval.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I can use " -itsoffset " option in ffmpeg command to give offset for audio or video to start.

Credits:
[How to combine a .mp4 video with a .wav audio with an offset in ffmpeg from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049970/how-to-combine-a-mp4-video-with-a-wav-audio-with-an-offset-in-ffmpeg-from-comm)

Comment: Will you please provide full command? I need same as you question.